# Need to get substring inside a string Forexample : the world is very beauty by describing color:blue and water,air,fire etc,

Tags: python, regex

Forexample : the world is very beauty by describing color:blue and water,air,fire etc,.
I need to get the word next to word "color".
For that I did small python script by getting the word "describing" index and also the index of word "and".So I can able to print within the index range there color:blue.

But In some cases, the word before "color" will dynamically change and after the word "blue" also dynamically change.So, in this scenraio, I am struggling here to how to put the regular expression to get the word "blue".

And the word next to color:blue.sometimes be like color:green.

I am just updating the question like,

I have set of string like For example "HELLO:rosa I am fine and you Good_Morning:U look very beauty temple:Will be in town.

Here I need to extract the string next to the word "Good_morning:" 
SO if, 
Input: "HELLO:rosa I am fine and you GOOD_MORNING:U look very beauty TEMPLE:Will be in town"

Output:U look very beauty
So the script need to do search for the string next to GOOD_MORNING which is small letters and it need to stop before the next Capital WORD(TEMPLE).and print that small letters alone there.

For that I did python script to get that string next to GOOD_MORNING but getting the whole string next to GOOD_MORNING like :U look very beauty TEMPLE:Will be in town" but not" U look very beauty".

Comment: So you are looking for a regular expression filtering your texts for color:something with a group capturing 'something'?

Comment: Yes i need that alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try `color:(\w+\b)`. It will always find the word next to `color:` (no spaces allowed).
https://regex101.com/r/IOkH1j/1

Comment: Can i have solution for that updated question

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/IOkH1j/2